# How to connect to MS SQL 2000 from PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, zend-framework, sql-server-2000

I use ZendFramework and PHP Version 5.4.12, my OS is Windows 7.
My parameters for connecting is

```
resources.db.adapter = "sqlsrv"
resources.db.params.pdoType = "mssql"
```

But I have this exception

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Native Client 11.0 does not support connections to SQL Server 2000 or earlier versions.'
```

because I use newest php driver.

How to connect to MS SQL Server 2000(version 8.00.760)?

Comment: as the error message says, that version of the driver doesn't support the old databases. downgrade your driver version.

Comment: I see only [Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)
Where can I get earlier versions ?

Comment: I use Zend and it does not have an Adapter to support PDO_ODBC

Comment: I tried use this parameters
`resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mssql"
resources.db.params.pdoType = "mssql"` but I got new error 
`The mssql driver is not currently installed`.
How to install pdo_mssql extension on php 5.4 ?

Comment: usually you would just uncomment that line in your php.ini. the mssql driver comes with most php installations but may not be active. You can also try to find it at http://pecl.php.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the version 2012 of the SQL Server Native Client (version 11) which no longer support the version 2000 of your SQL Server. Yes, it is a shame.

To fix that, you should download an earlier version that you can found here : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978

Look for the section

> Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Native Client

It is still not working, you need to uninstall the 2012 version first.

If it still not working, have a look here : http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1317581-2799-1.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I have a handful of databases that are still running SQL Server 2000 and I didn't want to revert to the older driver for everyone else. After some poking around this is the best workaround that I can come up: connect to SQL Server 2000 database using OLEDB via ADO. ADO is a COM component so you need to enable the `COM_DOT_NET` extension.

I have verified this still works with PHP 5.4 under Windows Server 2008 R2 with Native Client 11 installed.

```
<?php
$conn =  new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot create ADO COM object");
$conn->Open("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=LOCALHOST;Initial Catalog=master");
//$conn->Open("Provider=SQLOLEDB;User ID=username;Password=password;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=host.example.com;Initial Catalog=databasename"); 
$rs = $conn->Execute("SELECT 1 as Number,GetDate() as Date, CAST(0 as bit) as Boolean, 'hello world' as String");
$fieldnames = []; 
$rows = [];
while (!$rs->EOF){
  $fieldnames = []; // wasteful, redoing this each time
  $thisrow = [];
  for ($i=0;$i<($rs->Fields->Count);$i++)  {
    $field = $rs->Fields[$i];
    $fieldname = (string) $field->Name;
    $type = $field->Type;
    // field->Type is the ADO type; due personal weakness I am only handling types I actually need 
    if ($type == 3 || $type == 20) {
      $value = (integer) $field->Value;
    } elseif ($type == 4 || $type==5) {
      $value = (float) $field->Value;
    } elseif ($type == 11) {
      $value = (boolean) $field->Value;
    } else {
    $value = (string) $field->Value;
    }
    $thisrow[] = $value; //array by index
    $thisrow[$fieldname] = $value; // array by name
    $fieldnames[]=$fieldname;
  }
  $rows[] = $thisrow;
  $rs->MoveNext();
}
$rs->Close(); 
$conn->Close();
echo "your fieldnames are, in column order:\n";
var_dump($fieldnames);
echo "your data is, in record order:\n";
var_dump($rows);
?>
```

Notes:

- This only works for PHP under Windows.
- You need to enable the PHP COM_DOT_NET extension. Ugg. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678325/class-com-not-found) on how to do it.
- [This post at devnetwork.net](http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=134561) was essential in showing how to use ADO under PHP.
- The trick with using ADO is that the data is returned back as a COM Variant. The fastest way to use ADO is calling GetRows() and casting the variant returned as a 2D array of variants and going from there, but I could not get PHP to consume that. (This is "DrDev's" problem in aforementioned link.)
- To avoid problems, I walk through each field of each row and explicitly cast to a data PHP type. (This could be done better, but these were all the ADO types I cared about.)

To-do: parameterized queries. How I wish I could just get these hosts updated to SQL Server 2012 Express Edition instead...

Comment: This answer is useful for connecting a database using ADO in general, not only for Server SQL 2000. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks. Here's how to extend to parameterized queries using the cmd object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557606/how-do-i-associate-parameters-to-command-objects-in-ado-with-vbscript