# how to use vb variable in SQL statement in ASP?

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript

How to use variables declared in the asp VB can be used in the SQL statement for classic ASP?

Problem:

I have a variable

```
dim username
username = Request.Form("username")
```

Now I want to use this variable in where clause in the sql statement as shown below:

```
adoRS.Source = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username=  //This is where I want this variable to be..
```

What is the right syntax? Thankyou

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557606/how-do-i-associate-parameters-to-command-objects-in-ado-with-vbscript

Answer (score -2):

```
dim username
username = Request.Form("username")

adoRS.Source = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username= '"+userName+"'"
```

Comment: No! Evil! Huge security problem here.

Comment: What Joel is pointing out is something called SQL injection.  So while the answer will do what you need, search SQL injection on this site to understand why you should consider different approaches to this coding